# Can't run app on device when click sign up button

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-studio, insert

I have build an app that can insert and retrieve data into listview. i used database that placed on assets folder. When i run my app on device (xiaomi redmi note4) via usb debug but I can not sign up user when I click sign up button. this also happens to the emulator if I delete the database file in "/data/data/com.example.ibtb.bmkg/databases/" with logcat like this

```
    04-12 12:09:27.789 16299-16299/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: tb_user
04-12 12:09:27.794 16299-16299/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting email=t password=t nip=t username=t nama=t



                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tb_user (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tb_user(email,password,nip,username,nama) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1470)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
                                                       at com.example.ibtb.bmkg.database.DatabaseHelper.insertUser(DatabaseHelper.java:73)
                                                       at com.example.ibtb.bmkg.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:68)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22295)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

> here is my database code

```
   package com.example.ibtb.bmkg.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.model.Instrumen;
import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.model.User;
import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.model.Pengecekan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IBTB on 08/02/2018.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.ibtb.bmkg/databases/";
    public static String DB_NAME = "bmkgdb.db";
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void openDataBase()  {
        String dbPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        if (myDataBase != null && myDataBase.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
    }

    public long insertUser(User c){
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        /*String query = "select * from tb_user";
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        values.put("id_user", count); */

        values.put("nama", c.getName());
        values.put("nip", c.getNip());
        values.put("email", c.getEmail());
        values.put("username", c.getUname());
        values.put("password", c.getPass());
        openDataBase();
        long returnValue = myDataBase.insert("tb_user", null, values);
        closeDatabase();
        return returnValue;}

    public String searchPass(String uname) {

        myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select username, password from tb_user";
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
        String a, b;
        b = "not found";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                a = cursor.getString(0);
                //b= cursor.getString(1);

                if (a.equals(uname)) {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }

            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return b;
    }


    public List<Pengecekan> getListPengecekan() {

       // String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};

        Pengecekan pengecekan = null;
        List<Pengecekan> PengecekanList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT A.id_pengecekan, A.pengecekan, A.normal, B.nama_alat FROM  tb_pengecekan A, tb_alat B, tb_instrumen C  " +
                "WHERE C.id_instrumen = B.id_instrumen AND A.id_alat = B.id_alat AND C.id_instrumen = '9' ",  null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            pengecekan = new Pengecekan(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
           PengecekanList.add(pengecekan);

       /* if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            pengecekan = new Pengecekan(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
            PengecekanList.add(pengecekan);*/

            cursor.moveToNext();}

        cursor.close();
        close();
        return PengecekanList;
    }


    public Pengecekan getPengecekanId(int id) {
        Pengecekan pengecekan = null;
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT A.id_pengecekan, A.pengecekan, A.normal, B.nama_alat FROM  tb_pengecekan A, tb_alat B, tb_instrumen C  " +
                "WHERE A.id_pengecekan = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        pengecekan = new Pengecekan(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        //Only 1 resul
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return pengecekan;
    }

    public long updatePengecekan(Pengecekan pengecekan) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("pengecekan", pengecekan.getPengecekan());
        contentValues.put("normal", pengecekan.getNormal());
        contentValues.put("nama_alat", pengecekan.getNama_alat());
        String[] whereArgs = {Integer.toString(pengecekan.getId_pengecekan())};
        openDataBase();
        long returnValue = myDataBase.update("tb_pengecekan",contentValues, "id_pengecekan=?", whereArgs);
        closeDatabase();
        return returnValue;
    }

    public long addPengecekan(Pengecekan pengecekan) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("ID", pengecekan.getId_pengecekan());
        contentValues.put("pengecekan", pengecekan.getPengecekan());
        contentValues.put("normal", pengecekan.getNormal());
        contentValues.put("nama_alat", pengecekan.getNama_alat());
        openDataBase();
        long returnValue = myDataBase.insert("tb_pengecekan", null, contentValues);
        closeDatabase();
        return returnValue;
    }

    public boolean deletePengecekanById(int id) {
        openDataBase();
        int result = myDataBase.delete("tb_pengecekan",  "id_pengecekan =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        closeDatabase();
        return result !=0;
    }

    public List<Instrumen> getListInstrumen() {
        Instrumen instrumen = null;
        List<Instrumen> InstrumenList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  tb_instrumen  ", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            instrumen = new Instrumen(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1));
            InstrumenList.add(instrumen);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        close();
        return InstrumenList;
    }

    public Instrumen geInstrumenId(int id) {
        Instrumen instrumen = null;
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_instrumen WHERE id_instrumen = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        instrumen = new Instrumen(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1));
        //Only 1 resul
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return instrumen;
    }



}
```

> copy database

```
File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

> SignUp.Java

```
    package com.example.ibtb.bmkg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.model.User;

/**
 * Created by IBTB on 08/02/2018.
 */

public class SignUp extends Activity {
    private Button reg;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private EditText name, nip, email, uname, pass1, pass2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        reg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bsignupbutton);
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tfname);
                nip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tfnip);
                email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tfemail);
                uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tfuname);
                pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tfpass1);
                pass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tfpass2);
                String namestr = name.getText().toString();
                String nipstr = nip.getText().toString();
                String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
                String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
                String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
                String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();


                User c = new User(namestr, nipstr, emailstr, unamestr, pass1str);

                if (namestr.isEmpty() || nipstr.isEmpty() || emailstr.isEmpty() || unamestr.isEmpty() || pass1str.isEmpty() || pass2str.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast full = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please fill all the coloumn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    full.show();


                } else if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str)) {
                    Toast pass = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Password dont match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    pass.show();
                } else {

                /*c.setName(namestr);
                c.setNip(nipstr);
                c.setEmail(emailstr);
                c.setUname(unamestr);
                c.setPass(pass1str);*/

                    long result = dbHelper.insertUser(c);

                    Intent j = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(j);

                    if (result > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //back to main activity
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
            });
            }
        }
```

> MainActivity.Java

```
    package com.example.ibtb.bmkg;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.database.DatabaseHelper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Session session;
    //private Button button;
    DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        session = new Session(this);
       // button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        if(session.loggedin()){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class));
          finish();
        }
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.Blogin)
        {
            EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfusername);
            String str = a.getText().toString();

            EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfpassword);
            String pass = b.getText().toString();



           String password = myDbHelper.searchPass(str);
            if (pass.isEmpty() || str.isEmpty()) {
                Toast full = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter username and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                full.show();
            }
            else if(pass.equals(password))
            {
                session.setLoggedin(true);
                Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                i.putExtra("Username",str);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }

            else
           {
                Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username and Password dont match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                temp.show();
            }


        }

        if (v.getId()==R.id.Bsignup)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
/*
    public void press (View v){
        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ListPengecekan2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }*/

}
```

> Session.java

```
    package com.example.ibtb.bmkg;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
 * Created by IBTB on 06/04/2018.
 */

public class Session {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;

    public Session(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public void setLoggedin(boolean logggedin){
        editor.putBoolean("loggedInmode",logggedin);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean loggedin(){
        return prefs.getBoolean("loggedInmode", false);
    }
}
```

> ListPengecekan.java

```
    package com.example.ibtb.bmkg;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.adapter.ListPengecekanAdapter;
import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.ibtb.bmkg.model.Pengecekan;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class ListPengecekan extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvPengecekan;
    private TextView instrumen;

    private ListPengecekanAdapter adapter;

    private List<Pengecekan> mPengecekanList;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private DatabaseHelper myDbHelper;

    //Cursor c = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pengecekan);
        lvPengecekan = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_pengecekan);

        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Badd);
        myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        String instrumen = getIntent().getStringExtra("ins");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_instrumen);
        tv.setText(instrumen);

        File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME);
        if(false == database.exists()) {
            myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Copy db
            if(copyDatabase(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        //String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        mPengecekanList = myDbHelper.getListPengecekan();
        adapter = new ListPengecekanAdapter (this, mPengecekanList);
        lvPengecekan.setAdapter(adapter);


            }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mPengecekanList = myDbHelper.getListPengecekan();
        //Init adapter
        adapter.updateList(mPengecekanList);
    }

    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DB_PATH + DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.v("ListPengecekan", "DB copied");
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        // });

         }



    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

        String kondisi="";
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.B:
                if (checked)
                    kondisi = "Baik";

                break;
            case R.id.RR:
                if (checked)
                    kondisi = "Rusak ringan";
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListPengecekan.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogrusak, null);
                mBuilder.setTitle("Keterangan kerusakan");
                final Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) mView.findViewById(R.id.Spenanganan);
                final Spinner mSpinner1 = (Spinner) mView.findViewById(R.id.Shasil);
                final EditText kronologi = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.ekro);
                final EditText lapor = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.elapor);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListPengecekan.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.penaganan));
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListPengecekan.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hasil));
                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String Kronologi = kronologi.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, Kronologi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if (!mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih penanganan…")) {
                            Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }

                        if (!mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih hasil…")) {
                            Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, mSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }

                        String Lapor = lapor.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, Lapor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();




                    break;
            case R.id.RB:
                if (checked)
                    kondisi = "Rusak berat";

                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListPengecekan.this);
                View mView1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogrusak, null);
                mBuilder1.setTitle("Keterangan kerusakan");
                final Spinner mSpinner2 = (Spinner) mView1.findViewById(R.id.Spenanganan);
                final Spinner mSpinner3 = (Spinner) mView1.findViewById(R.id.Shasil);
                final EditText kronologi1 = (EditText) mView1.findViewById(R.id.ekro);
                final EditText lapor1 = (EditText) mView1.findViewById(R.id.elapor);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListPengecekan.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.penaganan));
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListPengecekan.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hasil));
                adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);

                mBuilder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String Kronologi = kronologi1.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, Kronologi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if (!mSpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih penanganan…")) {
                            Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, mSpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }

                        if (!mSpinner3.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih hasil…")) {
                            Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, mSpinner3.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }

                        String Lapor = lapor1.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(ListPengecekan.this, Lapor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                mBuilder1.setNegativeButton("Batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                mBuilder1.setView(mView1);
                AlertDialog dialog1 = mBuilder1.create();
                dialog1.show();

                break;
        }

        //myDbHelper.execSQl
    }
}
```

Comment: Try deleteing the App's data or uninstalling the App and then rerunning the App. If the same error happens then please edit the question to include the `DatabaseHelper` class and the code around the `SignUp$1.onClick`.

Comment: Please post the code of your database file.

Comment: i have been post my database sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your issue could be that the  `onCreate` method does nothing. if you delete an existing/useable database then there are no tables created.

You need to use `db.execSql(a_string_with_the_sql_to_create_your_tables);` in the `onCreate` method.

Something like :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,nama TEXT,nip TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(crtsql);
}
```

- Note you'd need to do the same for all the other tables. Noting that you need a db.execSQL for each as you can only run 1  SQL statement at a time.

An exception would be if you have other code that copies the database from the assets folder. If so including that would be relevant as if this is the case, this not working could be the issue.

### Edit re comments

It has been determined that issue is highly likely that the copy of the database from the assets folder is not being invoked.

To simplify the fix the following is suggested (rather than edit code) :-

1. Create a Java Class named `CopyDBFromAssets` i.e. file **CopyDBFromAssets.java** and copt the following into that class

:-

```
public class CopyDBFromAssets {

    private static final String TAG = "DBASSETCOPY";
    String mDBPath, mDatabasename;

    CopyDBFromAssets(Context context, String databasename) {
        mDatabasename = databasename;
        mDBPath = context.getDatabasePath(mDatabasename).getPath();
        if(!ifDatabaseExists(mDBPath)) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Attempting to copy database " +
                            mDatabasename +
                            " from assets folder."
            );
            if (copyDatabase(context)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Database " +
                        mDatabasename + " successfully copied.");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG,"Database " + mDatabasename + " NOT COPIED!!!");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(mDatabasename);
            String outFileName = mDBPath;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.v(TAG, "DB copied");
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean ifDatabaseExists(String dbpath) {
        File db = new File(dbpath);
        if(db.exists()) return true;
        File dir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

2. Edit **MainActivity.java** to add a single line to invoke the above as per

:-

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Session session;
//private Button button;
//DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); //<<<< COMMENTED OUT
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper; //<<<< ADDED
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CopyDBFromAssets cdbfa = new CopyDBFromAssets(this,DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME); //<<<< ADDED LINE
    myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); //<<<< ADDED LINE
    session = new Session(this);
   // button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    if(session.loggedin()){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class));
      finish();
    }
}
........ the rest of MainActivity.Java
```

### Notes

- `DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);` has been commented out and split into declaration and instantiation (set)
- check all lines with //<<<<

  3. After making the changes above delete the App's data and run. Check the log you should see something along the lines of

:-

```
04-12 12:39:31.672 1568-1568/soanswers.soanswers D/DBASSETCOPY: Attempting to copy database mydb from assets folder.
04-12 12:39:31.672 1568-1568/soanswers.soanswers V/DBASSETCOPY: DB copied
04-12 12:39:31.672 1568-1568/soanswers.soanswers D/DBASSETCOPY: Database mydb successfully copied.
```

- In the above the database used was called **mydb** rather than **bmkgdb.db**

Comment: may if i use db.execSql again on onCreate method even though it is using database in asset folder?

Comment: @gustu If you're using a Database from the assets folder then you'd not use `onCreate` *(basically it would cause issues as when `onCreate` is run the database has been just been created.)*. You need to look at whatever code copies the database from the assets folder *(there's none it in the DatabaseHelper as I looked for it)*. You sdidn't by any chance remove the database from the assets folder. That could well cause the issues you are facing.

Comment: please look sir, i've been post copies database. is that what you mean?

Comment: sory for disturbing  you sir, im newbie in android

Comment: What does the Toast say? It should either *Copy database succes* or *Copy data error*. Noting that you'll have to delete the App's data before running. can you also edit your question to include the `copyDatabase` method.

Comment: i have not put it on signup.java, do i have to put it on signup.java?

Comment: i've post the SignUp.java, MainActivity.java, and Session.java sir @MikeT

Comment: I can't see that the copyDatabase that you copied into the question is called from any of the code. Perhaps the issue is that you've inadvertently deleted that code. i.e. If it's there the after deleting the App's data you should see a Toast Saying Copy data.... If you're not seeing the toast then odds on the Database Copy isn't happening.

Comment: Copy Database is in another class (ListPengecekan.java). edited post

Comment: Ok that's the issue the copy from the assets MUST be done before trying to open the database otherwise you get an empty database if the database doesn't exist. I'll try to see what I can do but it's getting late here.

Answer (score -1):

You are inserting record into table which is not exist. Create table before performing insert operation.

Comment: i import the database and placed it in assets folder